# Broken Validation using numbers

Tags: java, validation

```
    public static void checkWeight(int startWeight, Number weight){
        System.out.println("HERE?!");
        y=false;
        System.out.println("HEHEHEH");
        mainLoop:{
            if((y==true)||(startWeight<=50)) {
                weight=startWeight;
                System.out.println("HERE");
                break mainLoop;
            }else{
            subMainLoop:{
                while(z==false) {
                    int userWeightCheck=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your cat's weight: "));
                        if(userWeightCheck<=50) {
                            System.out.println("OR HERE");
                            y=true;
                            z=true;
                            break subMainLoop;
                        }else {
                            System.out.println("Sorry, but that is not an acceptable input. Try again.");
                            continue;
                        }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hey all! I can't seem to fix this problem. I have added `System.out.println`'s to try and trouble shoot it myself. I've been scanning the internet for the past 1hr and a half, and still cannot find a solution. It prints `"HEHEHEH"`, and doe's not print "HERE", when it should be going through the if statement.

The call in my main class is like this:

```
int userWeight=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your cat's weight"));
Animal.checkWeight(userWeight, 51);
```

The issue is that when the user enters a number, it should work, if and only if the number is = or < 50. Otherwise, it pops up with a window asking for the user to re-enter their previous answer. Yet, it seems to be ignoring the loop completely.

Any help is massively appreciated! :)

Comment: And the issue is...? *"It prints "HEHEHEH", even when it has not met either conditions"* - There are no conditions to print that message.

Comment: Instead of using `System.out.println()` you should learn to use a debugger. That's more helpful in tracking down bugs.

Comment: "HEHEHEH" is printed before any condition is checked.

Comment: `System.out.println("HEHEHEH");` is right at the beginning of your function before any conditions are even tested. What are you talking about?

Comment: Side note: `mainLoop:{` - where's the loop?

Comment: the mainLoop:{ is the whole if statement.

Comment: That's a label.

Comment: Yes, a label for the whole loop itself.

Comment: What is `z`? Your first `if` statement will never be true, at least the first time through because `y` is false. Your `while` statement is contingent on `z` being false which as far as I can tell doesn't exist.

Comment: Your labels suggest there are two different loops `main` and `subMain` but there is only one loop here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I could do while trying to understand what you mean't and trying to keep the way you wrote it the same for whatever reason you are using for. I got rid of the labels and replaced them with whiles.

```
public static void checkWeight(int startWeight, Number weight) {
        System.out.println("HERE?!");
        boolean run = true;
        System.out.println("HEHEHEH");
        while (true) {

            if (startWeight <= 50) {
                weight = startWeight;
                System.out.println("HERE");
                break; // or "return weight" maybe?
            }

            while (run) {
                int userWeightCheck = 
Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your cat's weight: "));
                if (userWeightCheck <= 50) {
                    System.out.println("OR HERE");
                    run = false;
                    startWeight = userWeightCheck;
                    break; // or "weight" maybe?
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, but that is not an acceptable 
input. Try again.");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```